# Execution failed for task ':vision-camera-face-detector:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

Working on a React Native app project requires react-native-worklets-core npm package, after installing it when I "npm start" enter the command and selecting android after few moments it shows

```
The google-services Gradle plugin needs to be applied on a project with com.android.application or com.android.dynamic-feature.
C:\projects\and\projectone\node_modules\vision-camera-face-detector\android\src\main\java\com\visioncamerafacedetector\VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin.java:35: error: VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin is not abstract and does not override abstract method callback(Frame,Map<String,Object>) in FrameProcessorPlugin
public class VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin extends FrameProcessorPlugin {
       ^
C:\projects\and\projectone\node_modules\vision-camera-face-detector\android\src\main\java\com\visioncamerafacedetector\VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin.java:134: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
C:\projects\and\projectone\node_modules\vision-camera-face-detector\android\src\main\java\com\visioncamerafacedetector\VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin.java:141: error: cannot access Detector
      Task<List<Face>> task = faceDetector.process(image);
                                          ^
  class file for com.google.mlkit.vision.common.internal.Detector not found
C:\projects\and\projectone\node_modules\vision-camera-face-detector\android\src\main\java\com\visioncamerafacedetector\VisionCameraFaceDetectorPluginPackage.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    FrameProcessorPlugin.register(new VisionCameraFaceDetectorPlugin());
```

this error how to fix this issue, please help me to solve the issue
versions currently using--

```
"react-native": "0.73.2",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^3.8.0",
    "vision-camera-face-detector": "^0.1.8"
```

I have tried this cmd

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean
```

tried using downgrade the java from 21 to 17